# Cómo completar el ejercici@ usando un bucle for?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Alguien me puede decir cómo completar este ejercicio siguiendo mi lógica por favor?
Sé que estoy muy cerca porque se muestra la frase más larga, pero necesito que se muestre la palabra más larga. El tema es que no sé cómo iterar sobre las palabras en vez de sobre las frases

```js
function palabraMasLarga(array) {
   // La funcion llamada 'palabraMasLarga' recibe un array 'array' de frases (strings) como parametro
   // y debe devolver la palabra mas larga entre todas las frases ( Es decir la palabra con mayor cantidad de caracteres)
   // Por ej:
   // palabraMasLarga(['hola esto string', 'frase con palabra']) debe devolver 'palabra'

   // Tu código aca:
   var masLarga = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      if(array[i].length > masLarga.length){
         masLarga = array[i]
      }
   }
   return masLarga;
} 
console.log(palabraMasLarga(['this is reallylong', 'short words', 'hi'])) 
//RESULTADO: this is reallylong
```

Comment: busca sobre split.. tenes que partir el array en palabras...

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La solucion es simple como dice el comentario con split harias:

```java
public static String laPalabraMasLarga(String frases[]){
        var masLarga = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < frases.length; i++){
            var palabras = frases[i].split(" ");
            for(var j = 0; j < palabras.length; j++) {
                if(palabras[j].length() > masLarga.length()){
                    masLarga = palabras[j];
                }
            }

        }
        return masLarga;
    }
```

```java
System.out.println(laPalabraMasLarga(new String[]{"frase mas larga", "hola mundo", "dos mas dos son cuatro"}));
```

La respuesta es "cuatro"
Lo hice en java pero quitando cambios en sintaxis es lo mismo

Comment: Muchas gracias!